# Log4net rolling daily - Format of filename with date

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, config

I want My log file something like this **date.filename.txt**. which rolls out new file  everyday.

i am able to generate file in this format **filename.date.txt**. By using the below configuration

```
 <appender name="SLSILogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" >
  <converter>
    <name value="logfilename" />
    <type
   value="FilenamePatternConverter" />
  </converter>

  <conversionPattern
    value="%property{TestURL}%logfilename{LocalApplicationData}" />
</file>
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
<datePattern value="'.'yyyy.MM.dd'.log'" />
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

I've tried a lot of things but nothing helps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add the filename in the datePattern like:

```
<appender name="SLSILogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="c:\temp\logs\" />
<datePattern value="dd.MM.yyyy'.filename.log'" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
</appender>
```

Comment: Peer, Thanks for ur time on answering this.! 
I have one more query, if file name is the name of the machine how the syntax will be to access that.

Comment: I have added below code, and output file name is  **%date.filename.txt** . Please suggest how to remove % character

     `<datePattern type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
       <conversionPattern
        value="%yyyy.MM.dd.%property{MachineName}%'.log'" />
    </datePattern>`

Comment: I have posted the question, answer please :)